# net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationContext not set

Tags: corda

When upgrading from M13 to M14, I got the following runtime exception when testing the oracle in MockNetwork. Looks like the exception occurs when trying to build the filtered transaction.  For M14, I changed database to be CordaPersistence = configureDatabase(makeTestDataSourceProperties()).  Is there a way to make it work?

```
    @Test
    fun `sign - ok`() {
        database.transaction {
            val fxRateRequest = FXRateRequest(USD, EUR/*, LocalDate.now(), Tenor("1D")*/)
            val now = Instant.now()
            val fxRateResponse = FXRateContract.Sign(fxRateRequest, BigDecimal(0.8), TimeWindow.between(now, now.plusSeconds(30)))
            val command = Command(fxRateResponse, listOf(oracle_KeyPair.public))
            val state = FXRateContract.State(ALICE)
            val wtx: WireTransaction = TransactionType.General.Builder(DUMMY_NOTARY)
                    .withItems(state, command)
                    .toWireTransaction()
            val ftx: FilteredTransaction = wtx.buildFilteredTransaction(Predicate { x -> /*filterCmds*/fixCmdFilter(x) })

            val signature = oracle.sign(ftx)
            /** Post M13.0, we can use this instead of the assert */
//            wtx.checkSignature(signature)

            assert(signature.verify(ftx.rootHash.bytes))
        }
    }
```

Exception

```
Write-once property var net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationDefaults.P2P_CONTEXT: net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationContext not set.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Write-once property var net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationDefaults.P2P_CONTEXT: net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationContext not set.
    at net.corda.core.internal.WriteOnceProperty.getValue(WriteOnceProperty.kt:12)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationDefaults.getP2P_CONTEXT(SerializationAPI.kt)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.MerkleTransactionKt.serializedHash(MerkleTransaction.kt:16)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction$DefaultImpls.getAvailableComponentHashes(MerkleTransaction.kt:68)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction.getAvailableComponentHashes(WireTransaction.kt:20)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction$merkleTree$2.invoke(WireTransaction.kt:92)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction$merkleTree$2.invoke(WireTransaction.kt:20)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction.getMerkleTree(WireTransaction.kt)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.FilteredTransaction$Companion.buildMerkleTransaction(MerkleTransaction.kt:124)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction.buildFilteredTransaction(WireTransaction.kt:86)
    at argent.service.NodeFXRateTransactionTest_Mock$sign - ok$1.invoke(NodeFXRateTransactionTest_Mock.kt:121)
    at argent.service.NodeFXRateTransactionTest_Mock$sign - ok$1.invoke(NodeFXRateTransactionTest_Mock.kt:36)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:67)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:58)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:48)
    at argent.service.NodeFXRateTransactionTest_Mock.sign - ok(NodeFXRateTransactionTest_Mock.kt:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

The serialization framework we use became injected in M14 in preparation for a future change.  The `MockNetwork` should handle this for you but I don't see that in the stack trace you gave.  For standalone unit tests, try having your test class extend `net.corda.testing.TestDependencyInjectionBase`, which wraps each test in an initialisation and reset step to inject this for you.

If you can't extend from that class, then you can always replicate it's behaviour, but extending the class would be more future proof for when and if we need to inject other components in the future.